# Which Map provides moving objects to different index?

Tags: java, gwt, collections

I need a `Map` that takes Key-Value pair (probably `HashMap<String, Object>`) whereas the `Key` will be a `property` of the `Object` itself, like:

```
class Person {
  String name; //I know a string is not a good unique key, but ok to illustrate my example
}

Person person = new Person("John");
map.put(person.getName(), person);
```

Further, the map must provide an accessor similar to `ArrayList.add(idx, object)`. It should thereby also be possible to reorder an object to a different position and adjust the rest accordingly.

Which Map/List is suitable for this?

(by the way: I should be runable with GWT, so external libs might be problematic).

Comment: what do you mean move the object to a different index? you mean that the object's key was changed?

Comment: No, I mean the map should represent a stack, and I want to move the object to a different position to represent a different order of the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single standard container that does all of this.

However, a combination of a map and an `ArrayList` would satisfy all of your requirements.